# primefaces in-cell editing on a table with compound primary key

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.2 in-cell editing component to update an oracle DB table having compound primary key. The user should be able to edit also the primary key values but in this way if I use

```
em.merge(entity);
```

I got the following error

```
Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [voce] of class [entity.competenze_distaccati.CompetenzeDistaccatiPK] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

...which sounds reasonable to me. The question is: How can I give the user the possibility to change also the primary key values? 
rowEdit event listener is called with the changed value so I don't know which was the original record to perform a delete-insert.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing modification of Primary Key is not Correct Way of handling the data. Instead, allow for deletion and add the record again with required values. This way, you will be following the standards and also, your problem gets solved.

Comment: Thanks, using your advice I still allowed the user to modify the pk but the list of records modified gets not copied to db immediately but after a commit user command. In this way, at commit I do: listOfRecordToRemove = listFromDB.removeAll(listEdited)     while listOfRecordToInsert = listEdited.removeAll(listFromDB). To know only the records to update I have a HashSet populated by rowEdit event listener. That's worked for me.